# How do you cite a song at the start of a chapter?

Tags: citations, chapters

I've found that songs draw some people into something, so I was wondering how to cite a few lines from a song to draw someone in without making it look horrible.

Example:

> Somehow we have forgotten how to make a house a home
> - Big and Rich “That's why I pray”

Comment: Nobody seems to be giving direction on if I'm citing it the right way, or not.

Comment: I think yes, the citing is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ways I've seen it done seem to normally be pretty much the same. You'll put your song in the middle of the page or on the left, with the text arranged left. At the bottom, you'll put the author or writer below but arranged right, maybe with a line afterwards.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, since it could be songs, quotes, et al

Answer (score 0):

You do it the way you would use any quotation at the start of a chapter. Reduce the margins on both side so it sits in the middle of the page by itself and add a couple of line breaks after it. Some people add italics for the author. The title of the work and the author are usually right-justified.

Comment: is the citation correct, not the layout?

Comment: I would put the name of the song first.

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange way, but I read a few books with Chapter names very different.

You could maybe use that technique, in the sense that your chapter names could be the names of the songs you would want to quote.

Just a limitation, you would have to have songs for each of your chapters then, and also that over time, when your books grows old, the songs will also get old, and might not attract the audience as you would intend them to.

Comment: it's like getting your mind on the idea, and it's like doing quotes, and video clips also